# MKMapView and the responder chain

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have an MKMapView with a single subview:

```
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 200)];
subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[mapView addSubview:subView];
```

I would expect that because the subview does not handle any touch events, all touch events would be passed along to the parent map view (via the responder chain). I would then expect that panning and pinching in the subview would pan and pinch the map.

This, unfortunately, does not appear to be the case. Does anyone know of a way to get the map view in to the responder chain?

I realize overriding hitTest in my subview can achieve what I'm expecting here, but I can't use that approach because I have other gestures I need to respond to in the subview.

Answer (score 0):

How about handling all gestures with `UIGestureRecognizers` (properly setup to ignore other gesture recognizer or to fire simultanously with them) added to your mapView and disabling `userInteractionEnabled` of your subview?

I use the following code to listen to Taps on the mapView without interfering with the standard gestures:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mtd_handleMapTap:)];

// we require all gesture recognizer except other single-tap gesture recognizers to fail
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *systemTap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture;

        if (systemTap.numberOfTapsRequired > 1) {
            [tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:systemTap];
        }
    } else {
        [tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gesture];
    }
}


- (void)mtd_handleMapTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
if ((tap.state & UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

        // Get view frame rect in the mapView's coordinate system
        CGRect viewFrameInMapView = [self.mySubview.superview convertRect:self.mySubview.frame toView:self.mapView];
        // Get touch point in the mapView's coordinate system
        CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.mapView];

        // Check if the touch is within the view bounds
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(viewFrameInMapView, point)) {
             // tap was on mySubview
        }
}
```

}

Comment: I need my subview gestures to only operate when performed on the subview. I believe if I take this approach they'll be available over the entire mapview.

Comment: I edited my answer above, you can try to check if the gesture is within the frame of the subview